# How to force generic argument superclass type when implementing Map?

Tags: java, generics

I have all kinds of `GameObject`s. I want to make basic collection definition for them all:

```
//Wrong number of type arguments; required 2. > expected
public interface GameObjectMap<T> extends Map<String, T extends GameObject> {

}
```

The collection will allways be mapped by string (because the data are [loaded from JSON](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/static-data)). But the second generic type argument should be any instance of `GameObject`. I have no idea how to write the code above correctly.

Comment: what is wrong with the way you have it now? You can also do `public interface GameObjectMap extends Map<String, GameObject>`

Comment: Because of you had, say, `GameObjectBuilding extends GameObject`, you'd have to do `building = (GameObjectBuilding)map.get("factory_1");`. The whole point of generics is to define which type of objects does your class use before compiling (though compiled code actually doesn't use generics in any way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost right. Simply move the `extends GameObject` to the first generic definition:

```
public interface GameObjectMap<T extends GameObject> extends Map<String, T> {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The restriction comes on the first declaration of `T`, like

```
public interface GameObjectMap<T extends GameObject> extends Map<String, T> {

}
```